# Why is my PartialMock method ignoring my expectation

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino, partial-mocks

I've got a base class that I'm using as a PartialMock as such

```
1  IContextManager contextManager = mocks.StrictMock<IContextManager>();
2  target = mocks.PartialMock<EnumerationServiceBase>(new object[] { contextManager });
3  Expect.Call(delegate { contextManager.RemoveContext(guid); });
4  mocks.ReplayAll();
5  actual = target.ReleaseOp(request);
```

target.ReleaseOp(request) has a call to the contextManager.RemoveContext method which I've set an expectation for on line 3, but I still get the following error

Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: IContextManager.RemoveContext("e04c757b-8b70-4294-b133-94fd6b52ba04"); Expected #0, Actual #1.

This is the first test in which this hasn't worked (the other 45 or so are fine), but this is also the first one to use A) a partial mock, and B) a mocked method that returns void.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the first test in which this
>   hasn't worked (the other 45 or so are
>   fine), but this is also the first one
>   to use A) a partial mock, and B) a
>   mocked method that returns void. Any
>   ideas?

A) PartialMock means Rhino will intercept method calls *only* if it has an expectation on it. I think your usage here is fine.

B) Void methods shouldn't be a problem either.

Most likely, your problem is in your expectation:

```
Expect.Call(delegate { contextManager.RemoveContext(guid); });
```

The `guid` in your expectation needs to be the same instance as the guid passed in by `target`.

Try this:

```
Expect.Call(delegate { contextManager.RemoveContext(guid); }).IgnoreArguments();

// you can also use fluent syntax like this:
// contextManager.Expect(x => x.RemoveContext(guid)).IgnoreArguments();
```

If it works, you can be fairly sure your test guid and actual guid used in your class don't match.

Comment: Already tried this.  Even changed it to return something so it's not void.  I think the contextManager (passed in to the PartialMock method) isn't being associated to the proxy instance.  I'm going to create a property and explicitly set it to see if that resolves it.

Comment: Turns out an overload that takes a string was being called even when I passed null and said ignore arguments (the overload that takes a Guid was registered as the expected method).  In essence you were right Juliet.  I should have checked my parameters in the two more closely to notice a string was being passed and not a Guid.  Answer goes to you.